# Avoid confirmation on Ctr+C

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, conemu

Is there any way to terminate a job with one Hotkey or something like?
Right now I need confirm with extra hit on

> Y

or Hit again

> Ctr+C

I am using ConEmu.

Comment: I updated your tags to better match the topic of the question, aborting batch scripts.

Comment: Just look into hotkeys and search for "kill".

Comment: Kill is not stop a job. it's kill the process. and also have confirmation.